# CREATE TABLE is not working sql when adding invisible statement

Tags: oracle

Please help to resolve the CREATE table issue,
Missing right parenthesis bug when adding invisible statement, please check the below code and advise me.

```
create table can_table(
canno number(6,0) invisible generated by default as identity  
,canname nvarchar2(20)
);
```

Result

Error starting at line : 34 in command -
create table can_table(
canno number(6,0) invisible generated by default as identity
,canname nvarchar2(20))

Error report -
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:
*Action:

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? I cannot replicate the error in Oracle 18 [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=51281b60fd47b5e9666fd69b2c27fb70) and Oracle 11 [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=51281b60fd47b5e9666fd69b2c27fb70) raises that error but that is because it does not support either `INVISIBLE` or `GENERATED` columns as both syntaxes were only introduced in Oracle 12.

Comment: I am using below build and version 21.4.2.018, Build - 018.1706, Please suggest the version or link to use the oracle sql

Comment: Your statement works in Oracle 21.3 [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4a005d27a12e8e356a1153a6d7cbbaf9) (and Oracle does not appear to offer an Oracle 21.4 version for download, 21.3 is the current version). There is an Oracle SQL Developer version that is 21.4 but SQL Developer is **NOT** a database; it is a client application used to connect to a database. What is the output when you use `SELECT banner_full FROM V$VERSION;`?

Comment: _"Error starting at line : 34 in command "_   The command you show is much less than 34 lines.  There is no line 34.   Therefore, what you show is not in context, and the problem originates elsewhere.  Please update your question to show the entire context .  .

Comment: Thank you every one, after changing the version oracle data base to 21.c it is working

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in livesql

```
create table can_table(
canno number(6,0) invisible generated by default as identity  
,canname nvarchar2(20)
);

INSERT into can_table values ('XXX');

SELECT * from can_table;

CANNAME
XXX


SELECT canno, canname from can_table;

CANNO    CANNAME
1    XXX
```